# Positive integer not a power of 2 has an odd prime factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's given that if a positive integer $n$ is Not a power of two, then $n$ must have an odd prime factor, meaning
$$n = pr, p>2, 1\leq r< n $$
Is it really this trivial?  There's a [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers) that uses this result, without even giving an explanation why it's true.
If we assume $p=2$ why is that a contradiction?

Attempt:
If $r=1$, then $n = 2\cdot 1$, which is a power of two, hence contradiction.
Assume $n = 2k$ is a power of two, then $n=2(k+1) = 2k+2\cdot 1$, but there's no contradiction.

Comment: $1$ is a bit of an odd case since it doesn't really have _any_ prime factors, but it's true for $n \gt 1$.

Comment: Just writing $n=pr$ does not imply $p=2$, there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Prove by induction that every integer $n>1$ can be written uniquely as 
$$n=2^k \cdot m$$
with $m$ odd. This can also be proven using the prime factorization.

**Hint 2:** If $n$ is not a power of $2$ then $m$ is an odd number and $m>1$. This $m$ is divisible by a prime $p$. What can you say about $p$?

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is not a power of two, then it has a prime factor which is not two, by definition.

Comment: by whose definition?

Comment: Any definition! If the only prime factor is two, then it's a power of two.

Comment: Wait, what? You claim that if a product contains two as a factor then the product is a power of two???

Comment: If the **only** prime factor is two, then it's a power of two.

Comment: @Kundor it does not come merely from a definition. You need to use the fact that every number can be written as a product of primes.

Comment: You need to help me out here: the Only prime factor is 2.. ok,
$2\cdot 6 = 12$ not a power of two. 2 is the only prime factor

Comment: No, 6 has 3 as a prime factor

Comment: @Alvin Lepik This misunderstanding already appears in your question: it may be $n$ has 2 as a prime factor (so $p=2$ is *not* a contradiction) but this does not prevent it from having other prime factors (inside the $r$ in your question)

Comment: ok, then what is described is only possible when it contains one factor, 2 itself, multiply with anything else and you immediately get another prime factor.

Comment: Not necesarily, for example $4=2.2$ does not have any other prime factor than $2$. Coincidentally, $4$ is a power of two :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35649/discussion-between-sergio-and-alvin-lepik).

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction.

If $n > 1$ has no odd prime factor, then only prime factor of $n$ is $2$. So $n = 2^k$ for some $k > 0$ from fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: *Proof by contraction* is a nice name. But I guess you mean either [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) or [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).